# Column contributing Maximum in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using python 3.x I have pandas data frame df. df looks like

```
Name Maths Science Social studies
abc   80     70      90
cde   90     60      80 
xyz   100    80      85
...
...
```

I would like to generate a pandas data frame which will store student name, maximum marks & the subject contributed maximum marks. If maximum marks is 100 then it will consider next highest instead of 100. So my output data frame will look like

```
Name Highest_Marks Subject_contributed_Max
abc   90              Social Studies 
cde   90              Maths 
xyz   85              Social Studies
```

Can you suggest me how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
df2 = df.drop(columns='Name').mask(df.eq(100))

df['Highest_Marks'] = df2.max(axis=1)
df['Subject_contributed_Max'] = df2.idxmax(axis=1)
```

output:

```
  Name  Maths  Science  Social studies  Highest_Marks Subject_contributed_Max
0  abc     80       70              90           90.0          Social studies
1  cde     90       60              80           90.0                   Maths
2  xyz    100       80              85           85.0          Social studies
```

For efficiency, avoiding computing twice the max/idxmax, you can compute the `idxmax` and use a [lookup](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-lookup)

```
s = (df
 .drop(columns='Name')
 .mask(df.eq(100))
 .idxmax(axis=1)
)

idx, cols = pd.factorize(s)
df['Highest_Marks'] = df.reindex(cols, axis=1).to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df)), idx]
df['Subject_contributed_Max'] = s
```

Comment: @ArchAngelPwn `b'QXJlIHlvdSBzdXJlIGh1bWFuPw=='`

Answer (score 1):

This will work

```
df_melt = df.melt('Name')
df_melt = df_melt.loc[df_melt['value'] < 100]
df_melt['RN'] = df_melt.sort_values(['value'], ascending=False).groupby(['Name']).cumcount() + 1
df_melt.loc[df_melt['RN'] == 1].sort_values('Name')
```

Comment: it should work, but sorting adds complexity to the computations ;)

Comment: Yea, yea yea, I've already been studying your code to try and "steal" it haha

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```py
df = df.set_index('Name').stack().reset_index().rename(columns={
    'level_1':'Subject_contributed_Max', 0:'Highest_Marks'}).sort_values(
    ['Name','Highest_Marks'])
df = df[df['Highest_Marks'] != 100].groupby('Name').last().reset_index()[[
    'Name', 'Highest_Marks', 'Subject_contributed_Max']]
```

Input:

```
  Name  Maths  Science  Social studies
0  abc     80       70              90
1  cde     90       60              80
2  xyz    100       80              85
```

Output:

```
  Name  Highest_Marks Subject_contributed_Max
0  abc             90          Social studies
1  cde             90                   Maths
2  xyz             85          Social studies
```

---

**UPDATE**:

Here is a faster approach than my original answer above. It's similar to one of the suggestions in @mozway's answer, though it uses `where()` instead of `mask()` (and it also only returns the high marks, not the individual columns of marks).

```py
    df2 = df.set_index('Name')
    df2 = df2.where(df2 < 100)
    df2 = df2.assign(**{'Highest_Marks':df2.max(axis=1).astype(int), 
        'Subject_contributed_Max':df2.idxmax(axis=1)}).reset_index()[[
        'Name', 'Highest_Marks', 'Subject_contributed_Max']]
```

Prompted by a comment by OP, I ran some benchmarks on answers by @mozway and me (I also tried adding the answer by @ArchAngelPwn, but it doesn't seem to give comparable output in its current form).

Here are the results for a 1000 row by 9000 column dataframe:

```
Timeit results:
foo_1 (orig) ran in 2.4102477666456252 seconds using 3 iterations
foo_2 (refined) ran in 2.256996333327455 seconds using 3 iterations
foo_3 (where) ran in 1.1588773333545153 seconds using 3 iterations
foo_4 (mozway mask) ran in 1.17148056665125 seconds using 3 iterations
foo_5 (mozway mask lookup) ran in 1.1049298333236948 seconds using 3 iterations
```

Comment: I have pandas data frame with 40000 rows & 40000 columns. I'm applying your solution on that data frame. I tried almost all the approaches. But it's running for more than 6 hours. Can you please suggest some time optimal solution?

Comment: A 3000x9000 df uses 216MB of memory. By extension, a 40k x 40k df (that's about 60x larger than the 3000x9000, or 1.6 billion cells) would use about 13GB or memory. When I run the original code in my answer on a 3000x9000 df, `timeit` says it take about 20 seconds, and the solutions by @mozway take about 10 seconds (this is very approximate). So if I were to increase the df size by a factor of 60x, assuming the df size didn't overwhelm my system's 16GB of RAM, it should take about 20 minutes. If yours is still not finished after 6 hours, your system is likely memory constrained.

Comment: Since your question can be neatly segmented by row, you could try dividing your 40,000 rows into blocks of say 400 rows each and iterating over these 100 blocks (i.e., loading from persistent store, processing, and writing the results to persistent store one block at a time).